# How to prevent a remote process from being closed in Windows?

Tags: c#, windows, winapi, hook

There is a program which I can't modify it's code having been opened. I want to create a "watcher" to hook the closing event of that program in order to make the main window of the program hidden rather than being closed when users try to close that program.

I have googled it and someone says hook the API named `OpenProcess` would work. I tried using a C# lib called "EasyHook" and succesfully inject a remote process and hook `MessageBeep` API. Then I tried hooking `OpenProcess` and `TerminateProcess`, but the hooked methods of those two methods were never called.

So what is the proper method should I hook or is there any other way can realize my purpose? If there is no way to prevent the process being terminated with task manager, is there any tricks  like hooking the close button of the window etc.?

PS. I don't know kernel programing of Windows and driver programing, so I want to realize it in user mode if it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to create a "watcher" to hook the closing event of that program in order to make the main window of the program hidden rather than being closed when users try to close that program.

There is no process close event that you can hook. However, for GUI programs, there are [`WM_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-close) and [`WM_SYSCOMMAND|SC_CLOSE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/wm-syscommand) window messages that you can intercept with [`SetWindowsHookEx()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexw).

> I have googled it and someone says hook the API named OpenProcess would work.

Whoever said that hooking `OpenProcess()` is the solution to this was either mistaken, or you misread what that hook was actually being used for.

> I tried using a C# lib called "EasyHook" and succesfully inject a remote process and hook MessageBeep API. Then I tried hooking OpenProcess and TerminateProcess, but the hooked methods of those two methods were never called.

Of course, because you tried to hook them in the process that is being terminated, but that is not where they are called from, they are called in the process that is doing the terminating (ie, in Task Manager itself).

> If there is no way to prevent the process being terminated with task manager

If the brute force "End Process (Tree)" option is used, then there is no option to catch/block that.  The "End Task" option on the "Application" tab tries to perform a graceful termination using window messages before it resorts to brute force.

> is there any tricks like hooking the close button of the window etc.?

See my first comment above.